# How to compile iText 5.5.x with older version of java 1.3.1

Tags: itext, javac

I would like to have the procedure to compile iText 5.5.x using Javac 1.3.1.

We have a old application that can perform java calls but it is only certified with Java 1.3.1.

Note that I'm novice to java, so a step by step would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Step 1) Resign from your job.  Step 2) Look for a Java job that uses 1.6 at least.

Comment: The would be quite much work! If you use iText 2.1.7 (which was compiled with Java 1.4) it may be doable however this version has been deprecated for a while. However since Java 1.3 is deprecated much longer you probably don't care ;-)